# How to calculate touching figure sizes swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm currently making a **scanner app** with **Swift3**, I need to **calculate touching figure size** in UIView, Now I'm leaving a question. Please inform me **How to calculate touching figure sizes and how to resolve.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific needs, currently it is unclear what you are asking: Illustrate your view hierarchy, you have currently implemented, maybe also some code and what kind of "touching figure sizes" do you mean?

Comment: sorry sir ... i want to touching space width(figure width)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the question but perhaps this could help you:

```
let button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

func btnClicked(sender: UIButton){

    //Here you have the size of a button touched
    let figure_touched_height =  sender.frame.size.height
    let figure_touched_width = sender.frame.size.width

}
```